# Error: Unresolvable dependency resolving $resource in clas JsonResource in file Container.php

Tags: laravel, api

I am having this issue when I am trying to make a POST call to a resource. I am striving with this error for hours. Can somebody please help me?

api.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register')->name('register');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('details', 'UserController@details');
    Route::apiResource('schedule', 'ScheduleController');
});
```

ScheduleController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Schedules;
use App\Http\Resources\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ScheduleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        return Schedule::collection(Schedules::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Schedule $request)
    {
        $schedule = new Schedules();

        if (isset($request['title'])) {
            $schedule->title = $request['title'];
        };

        if (isset($request['start'])) {
            $schedule->start = $request['start'];
        };

        if (isset($request['end'])) {
            $schedule->end = $request['end'];
        };

        if ($schedule->save()) {
            return response()->json(new Schedule($schedule), 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Error can\'t save schedule', 500);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Schedule $id)
    {
        return response()->json(new Schedule(Schedules::find($id)), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Schedule $id)
    {
        if (Schedules::find($id)->delete()) {
            return response()->json('Success on delete carpet', 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Error can\'t delete carpet', 500);
        }
    }

    public function creazaProgramare(Schedule $request)
    {
        $schedule = new Schedules();

        if (isset($request['title'])) {
            $schedule->title = $request['title'];
        };

        if (isset($request['start'])) {
            $schedule->start = $request['start'];
        };

        if (isset($request['end'])) {
            $schedule->end = $request['end'];
        };

        if ($schedule->save()) {
            return response()->json(new Schedule($schedule), 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Error can\'t save schedule', 500);
        };
    }

}
```

ScheduleResource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Schedule extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
                'title' => $this->title,
                'start' => $this->start,
                'end' => $this->end
        ];
    }
}
```

Schedule Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedules extends Model
{
    //
}
```

I tried to run "composer install" as I saw on other people. It seems that problem is comming from JsonResource line 55(constructor) but I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate you're help

Comment: put code, not images of code in your question

Comment: sure, I edited the post :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you are passing your api resource class to response()->json(...). I also found that in your controller store method you pass Schedule which is an api resource and not a request object.

```
if ($schedule->save()) {
    //check below since its a resource, that should be enough
    return new Schedule($schedule);
  } else {
    return response()->json('Error can\'t save schedule', 500);
 };
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I changed in ScheduleController line "public function store(Schedule $request)" into "public function store(Request $request)". I really apreciate you're help

Answer (score 0):

I tried both solution and it does not work.

The error that I am facing is:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: **Unresolvable dependency resolving** [Parameter #0 [ <required> **$resource** ]] in class Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json**JsonResource** in file Illuminate\Container**Container.php on line 1032**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps sharing your error/exception would give us more details in what is happening.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register')->name('register');
//change here below
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function(){
    Route::post('details', 'UserController@details');
    Route::apiResource('schedule', 'ScheduleController');
});
```

This may fix your issue. However, sending showing the exception would help.